# Why does $(a^{\frac{1}{b}})^b$ not simplify to $a$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why does Mathematica not simplify double exponential such as

```
(a^(1/b))^b
```

Is it because `b` might be zero? And how to resolve that issue?

Comment: Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0, Simplify[(a^(1/b))^b]]

Comment: What about $a=-1$ and $b=1/2$?  Look up `PowerExpand` and be sure to read the Details section of its documentation.  This is certainly a duplicate as this used to be one of the most common questions, but I can't find a good existing answer ... can anyone else find it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a very common question among beginner Mathematica users.

The answer is that the simplification isn't carried out because it is not generally valid.  Example with $a = -1$, $b = 1/2$:

$$
\bigl( (-1)^2 \bigr)^\frac{1}{2} = 1^\frac{1}{2} = 1 \neq -1
$$

The same applies to why $(a b)^c$ is not expanded to $a^c b^c$ or why the more general $(a^b)^c$ doesn't expand to $a^{b c}$.

There are multiple solutions to deal with this.

**Specify assumptions that make the transformation valid:**

```
Simplify[(a^(1/b))^b, b ∈ Integers]
(* a *)
```

```
Simplify[(a^(1/b))^b, a > 0 && b > 0]
(* a *)
```

In Mathematica, the inequalities also imply that `a` and `b` are real.

**Use `PowerExpand`**

`PowerExpand` explicitly ignores the fact that this kind of transformation is not generally valid, and performs it anyway.  Be sure to read under *Details* in [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html)!

```
PowerExpand[(a^(1/b))^b]
(* a *)
```

In "recent" versions (maybe since v6.0?), `PowerExpand` will do exact transformations if `Assumptions` is set to something else than `Automatic`.

```
PowerExpand[(a^(1/b))^b, Assumptions -> True]
(* a E^(2 I b π Floor[1/2 - Im[Log[a]/b]/(2 π)]) *)
```

Comment: I couldn't find a duplicate so I wrote up something that could be used as a canonical answer.